# How do I pin a remote desktop connection to the taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, taskbar

If you create a remote desktop .rdp file (with stored credentials etc) and drag it to the taskbar in Windows 7, it doesn't behave as expected when you click it.

Clicking the pinned shortcut on the taskbar simply opens the remote desktop dialog box, instead of immediately connecting like a similar shortcut on the desktop would do quite happily.

**How can I get the same shortcut pinned to my taskbar so I only have to click it once to connect?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can create a shortcut on, e.g., the desktop (right-click the desktop, select "New > Shortcut"), with the following command line:

```
%windir%\system32\mstsc.exe "C:\Path\To\My\RDF File.RDP"
```

If you pin this shortcut to the taskbar, remote desktop should directly launch the connection.

Comment: This doesn't solve the fact that I cannot use Win+<Number> to access e.g. an already open Remote Application window

Comment: On Windows 10 the icon is pinned to the task bar, but when you click on it a new window is opened that is not pinned. So you can't pin your RDP session in place relative to other windows.

Answer (score 5):

Once you save your remote connection setup in an RDP file simply drag the file to the Remote Desktop icon in the Task Bar. This adds this connection to the "Pinned" area when you right-click the Remote Desktop ICON. You can add as many RDP file connections as you want to this pinned area. This assumes that you have already added the Remote Desktop program to the Task Bar. See above for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on the pinned icon, it will show you a list of recent connections. It should account for saved credentials and such as well.

Comment: But it will not launch RemoteApp's, it will just log the user into that machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you liked the old Quick Launch area, you can use the Free Launch Bar (after installing, it is enabled/disabled by right-clicking the taskbar>Toobars):

http://www.freelaunchbar.com/

You can then set up as many RDP icons as you want more easily. You will see in this picture, I have 4. This is a picture of Windows 7.

[image]