# How do I pin a remote desktop connection to the taskbar win Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, taskbar

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/298974/how-do-i-pin-a-remote-desktop-connection-to-the-taskbar) asks about pinning a Remote Desktop Connection to the task bar in Windows 7. The methods given in the answers no longer work in Windows 10, at least not the way I want them to.

I want to pin a Remote Desktop Connection to a specific computer to the task bar in Windows 10. I want to be able to click on it an immediately open the RDP connection without further clicking. The method given in the previous question simply opens the RDP client window, requiring a further click on the "connect" button before opening the session.

The session should open with the saved settings for that machine (saved in a `.rdp` file).

I have tried creating a shortcut to the a `.rdp` file and pinning that to the task bar, but it opens a separate window rather than expanding the pinned icon to the RDP client app itself. That means it is impossible to pin the opened RDP window in place relative to other windows on the task bar.

Comment: Are you asking for an icon that will open up RDP on a given `.rdp` file and do the Connect automatically?

Comment: Yes, but also not create an extra new window on the taskbar. On Windows 7 and 8 I had it so that I pinned the icon on the far left of the task bar, and when clicked it expanded into a full window, also on the far left of the task bar. On Windows 10 pinning the shortcut opens a new window on the right hand side of the task bar.

Comment: You mean that the same taskbar icon that was used to launch the RDP session was reused for the opened RDP window?

Comment: Yes, precisely.